# TYPO3 + RealURL = Multilanguage Homepage doesn't work (404)

Tags: typo3, realurl

I ran into serious trouble with RealURL and TYPO3. Here's the scenario.

I'm working on a website using German by default and offering English translations. So far that works great. The URLs look something like this: `http://mydomain.com/en/about-us`

The root page as such works only in German, the default language `http://mydomain.com/`

Once I'm using it like this `http://mydomain.com/en/` i end up with a 404 message.
The page as such works when I hand it some GET variables like this `http://mydomain.com/?L=1`

I was unable to fix this issue as of yet.

The page tree looks a bit like this

`* Common Root (Standard page)

|-> * Common Data  (Folder)

|-> * mydomain.com (Standard Page / Rootpage enabled)

----|-> Homepage (Shortcut to "mycomain.com", used for navigation only)

----|-> About us (Standard page)

----|-> Contact (Standard page)`

I suspect this shortcut page to cause some trouble however wasn't able to do anything about it.

The RealURL Config is auto generated so no fancyness in there.

I'm using TYPO3 4.7.7 with RealURL 1.12.3.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this problem?

cu
Roman

Comment: Can you share your realurl configuration?

Comment: We need the RealUrl config to help you, whether it's autogenerated or not.

I strongly suspect something is messed up or missing with the language config.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem using TYPO3 6.0.0 and also RealURL 1.12.3. Though I wasn't able to find out the cause, I just realized that the following workaround helped me:

Try to replace your current home page with a copy of itself (don't forget to define it as rootpage in your RealURL configuration).